# Ages of Radha and Krishna?

Tags: krishna, radha

What are the ages of Radha and Krishna when they were in love with each other while both are not get separated?

Comment: Trust me, your question is going to receive a variety of answers.

Comment: Radha married Ayan das, maternal uncle of Krishna, but even before Krishna left vrindavan, in fact in her adolescence. It is said that radha used to go to meet Krishna in disguise from her husband's house.

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/how-was-radhaji-born-what-are-the-names-of-her-father-and-mother/20496#20496

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How was Radhaji born? What are the names of her father and mother?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/how-was-radhaji-born-what-are-the-names-of-her-father-and-mother)

Comment: The linked post answers only second part.

Comment: @AniruddhaSarkar, But having an affair even after being married is a sin in hinduism. Right?