# Who is Ayan ghosh in Dwapara yuga?

Tags: krishna, radha

Who is Ayan ghosh in Dwapara yuga? Under what circumstances and when Radha got married to Ayan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was Radha aunt of Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31795/16823)

Comment: Radharani married Rayana. Check https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/how-was-radhaji-born-what-are-the-names-of-her-father-and-mother

Comment: Seems Rayana is misspelt. Correct spell name is 'Ayan'